# Form input very slow / delayed when typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, semantic-ui-react

I have a form comprised of 2 objects - A and B both objects have around 20 variables in them.

When it type there is a couple of seconds delay before the state is updated with the value.

My state is along the lines of this where the data is passed in from a parent component:

```
export class Booking extends Component<any, BookingProps & BookingState> {
 
  constructor(bookingProps: BookingProps) {
    super(bookingProps);

    this.state = {
      a: bookingProps.a,
      b: bookingProps.b,
      errors: {}
      ... around six other objects for modal, default data etc
    };
  }
```

Many of the input form form fields are like this:

```
      <Form.Field>
        <label htmlFor="ref">Ref</label>
        <input
          placeholder="Ref"
          value={this.state.a.ref}
          id="ref"
          onChange={this.handleBookingFieldChange}
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgrey' }}
        />
      </Form.Field>
```

In the other form fields part of state.b it is exactly the same except the value is `this.state.b.ref` and the onChange is `onChange={this.handleBookingExtrasChange}`.

So essentially i have separate onChange handlers for state a and b:

```
  private handleBookingFieldChange = (e: any) => {
    const key = e.target.id;
    const value = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      booking: { ...this.state.a, [key]: value }
    });
  };
```

So when i type it takes around 3 seconds for the letters to appear in the text field. I'm new to  React (from Angular) and can't think why this would take so long to display what i typed.

I would guess that the state is updating every field but i'm not sure. What can i do to speed it up?

Comment: do not trigger an event on every keystroke but instead implement a timeout that gets clearer on every keystroke and only calls your functions such as ajax calls and what not after the timeout has been allowed to expire.

Comment: But how do i update value if not on onChange?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Why do you using `this.state.a.ref` instead of just `this.state.a`?

Comment: state.a is an object with about 20 fields in. it's not a single field

Answer (score 1):

I found that by switching the input a little will work as you type - essentially setting `defaultValue` instead of`value` and using `onBlur` instead of `onChange`. Now the form fields update when typing:

```
      <Form.Field>
        <label htmlFor="ref">Ref</label>
        <input
          placeholder="Ref"
          defaultValue={this.state.a.ref}
          id="ref"
          onBlur={this.handleBookingFieldChange}
          type={'number'}
        />
      </Form.Field>
```